# Detener listener de firebase en android (Realtime database)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin

estoy realizando una App en Android Studio con Kotlin como lenguaje, pero tengo un problema al intentar desvincular el realtime, ya he intentado con la función `removeEventListener` pero no hace nada, el listener continua funcionado, también he intentado finalizand el Activity, pero de igual manera el listener continua funcionando hasta que la aplicación completa finaliza.

Estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
val firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     firebase.child("$user/time").addValueEventListener(listenerTime)
}

private val listenerTime = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("listenerTime", databaseError.message)
    }
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
         if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            /** Do something **/
         } else { 
            firebase.removeEventListener(this)
         }
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    firebase.removeEventListener(listenerTime)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para remover el listener de Firebase debes realizarlo  de la siguiente forma, importante revisar si el listener fue inicializado y no tiene valor null:

**KOTLIN:**

```
   override fun onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy()
        if (listenerTime!= null) {
            dbRef.removeEventListener(listenerTime);
        }
    }
```

**JAVA:**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (listenerTime!= null) {
        dbRef.removeEventListener(listenerTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, estaba haciendo mal las referencias, estaba tomando como referencia la variable `firebase` que es la referencia.

Comment: Excelente @AbrahamMontes saludos!

Answer (score 0):

recuerda el ciclo de vida de la app

Si llamas el listener en `onStart` -> lo quitas en `onStop`

Si lo llamas en `onResume` -> lo quitas en `onPause`

Si lo llamas en `onCreate` -> lo quitas en `onDestroy`

solo recuerda que onDestroy no se llama siempre, coloca un Toast en onDestroy y revisa si se esta llamando

BTW, No creo que eso sea valido

```
 } else { 
        firebase.removeEventListener(this)
 }
```